# RSpec let error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

In my spec/models/user_spec.rb I have the next:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { 5.times { FactoryGirl.create(:sport) } }
  before { let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }

  ...

end
```

But when running my user_spec.rb I'm getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: before { let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `let' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x000001043033b0>
```

Which is weird because my specs have been working until now, and I haven't changed anything...

Here is my gemfile: https://gist.github.com/4690919

Here is my spec_helper.rb: https://gist.github.com/4690935

I'd appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: your spec_helper is "spec/models/"? or just "/spec"?

Comment: my spec_helper is in /spec

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know why it was working before, but you should never have a `let` block inside of a `before` block. It should be called from within a `describe` (or `context`) block, like this:

```
describe User do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { 5.times { FactoryGirl.create(:sport) } }
  ....
```

See [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Let/ExampleGroupMethods) for details.